# Change the default browser to X with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, browser

I installed Google Chrome, which sets the default browser to itself. After I uninstall Chrome, I can't open web browser from the links in Lotus Notes.

How can I set Internet Explorer back to the default browser?

Comment: What did you not like about Chrome?

Comment: What did you not like about Chrome so much that you decided to use IE instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Internet Explorer.

Go to Tools > Internet Options > Programs. Press `Make Default`.

Click OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to "default programs" in the start menu's search bar, you can set IE as your default browser from there, too.

Answer (score 1):

Open Default Programs, select 'Set Program Access and Computer defaults', click on the button with two arrows pointing downward for 'Custom', under 'Choose a Default web browser' select the radio button for 'Internet Explorer'.(In our Enterprise Environment IE is the default browser in Lotus Notes).

Answer (score 0):

If setting it in the browser pref of IE or setting it in set program defaults doesn't work, you may have to set it in the location doc within lotus notes.

If you are on version 7 or lower of notes, go into file-->locations-->edit current location, then click on the browser tab, and change it to IE.  If it's already on IE but not working, change it to something else, save it and then change it back.

In version 8 of notes, its file-->locations-->manage locations-->click the location and then click edit.